# Opening a bootstrap modal on click of a custom button on standard salesforce page

Tags: apex, javascript, jquery, bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal that I want to open on click of a Custom button on the standard Salesforce page.

So for that I need to Execute a Javascript on the 'Onclick' action of the button (that'll be how the custom button will be configured)

Can anybody guide me as to how should I go about writing the jQuery?

The code for modal bootstrap looks like this:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false"  standardController="Festival__c" extensions="MyController" showHeader="false" >

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myModal").modal('show');
});
</script>
```

here myModal is the Id of the modal dialog that contains the fields that the user needs to enter and click either `SAVE` or `CANCEL`

Comment: What issue are you having? Looks like you have the correct line to open the modal. The selector could be changed to $('[id$=myModal]') though if you do not have tags on every element

Comment: hey Eric..I want to open the popup on click of a custom button. I am confused how to call this bootstrap modal (in html) using jquery

Comment: Use $("#myModal").modal('show'); in the onclick of the button

Comment: This will not work because 'MyModal' does not exist when the button is clicked and hence the error shows up

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Abandoned

Answer (score 3):

You're going to run in to a number of issues with this.

**1)** Your modal window requires style sheets. Stylesheets cannot be added to a standard page layout.

**2)** The modal dialog has to be created prior to you calling your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $("#myModal").modal('show'); });
```

**3)** **And this is the hardest part**: It sounds as if you want to have an inline form within this modal window. This is not possible without dynamically creating all your form elements in javascript. This is not a good idea - and will be very costly.

To pull this off, **I would do the following**:

1) Within your custom button: your script would need to dynamically create the stylesheet links. These sheets will be dumped on the page only when a user clicks the button.

2) Create your modal dialog dynamically as per **Eric's answer** (I'm not familiar with bootstrap). Since you have the style sheets and scripts on the page, the modal window will look normal. In the `onHide` attribute of the modal: add something to refresh the page: `window.location.reload`

3) Instead of attempting to dynamically create your html form on the click of the button: create a visualforce page that does what you need. You can make it iframe friendly by using the page attributes to hide unneeded elements. eg:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStyleSheets="true" showChat="false" sidebar="false"> 
<!-- Your form, and save button here -->
</apex:page>
```

Now, the content of the modal window will just need to be an **iframe** to the custom visualforce page.

On the page, include all needed fields, and a save button.

**The end result** will be a modal window that iframes out to a completely versatile, and yet separately managed visualforce page. when the user makes edits, he clicks save. Once saved, he can close the modal window - at which point the script `window.location.reload` is called: and the edits are now visible, and the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the modal into your page's html.

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <!-- [MODAL BODY] -->
</div>
```

It will not render by default because of `aria-hidden="true"`.

Then you can trigger the modal block to appear with a few attributes on a button. For example, if you can also use an outputLink:

```
<apex:outputLink styleClass="btn btn-primary" value="#myModal" html-data-toggle="modal">Click me!</apex:outputLink>
```

Bootstrap's engine will do the magic.

Check this working example (no VF): http://jsfiddle.net/5XM3J/

Comment: He mentioned he is on a standard page layout. The VF tag is not applicable - but yes: he does need to plop the element in to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Since you do not have an element on the page you can add this to your button code:

```
BootstrapDialog.show({
            title: 'Your Title',
            message: 'Your Message,
            size: BootstrapDialog.SIZE_LARGE,
            onhide: function(dialogRef){
                //Code to execute on hide
            }   

        });
```